# Concerns about octree implementation for Barnes-Hut algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to implement quadtree for my barnes-hut algorithm implementation. I am not sure that the code I've wrote so far is good implementation - it is dirty, and tend to be slow. Of course I am also aware that the results might be correct, but I'd be glad if someone can take a look at that and give me a hints. Because the whole code is very big and also includes OpenGL visualization, I am putting here only important parts. I hope that's ok.

**Quadtree.h**

```
Quadtree* trees[2][2][2];
glm::vec3 vBoundriesBox[8];
bool leaf;
float combined_weight = 0;
std::vector<Element*> objects;
```

**Quadtree.cpp**

```
#define MAX_LEVELS 5

void Quadtree::AddObject(Element* object)
{
    this->objects.push_back(object);
}

void Quadtree::Update()
{
    if(this->objects.size()<=1 || level > MAX_LEVELS)
    {
        for(Element* Element:this->objects)
        {
            Element->parent_group = this;
            this->combined_weight += Element->weight;
        }
        return;
    }

    if(leaf)
    {
        glm::vec3 newBoundries[8];

        // 0,0,0
        newBoundries[0] = vBoundriesBox[0];
        newBoundries[1] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[0].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[1].x - vBoundriesBox[0].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[0].y,vBoundriesBox[0].z );
        newBoundries[2] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[0].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[1].x - vBoundriesBox[0].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[0].y,vBoundriesBox[0].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[3].z - vBoundriesBox[0].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[3] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[0].x,vBoundriesBox[0].y,vBoundriesBox[0].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[3].z - vBoundriesBox[0].z)/2.0f));

        newBoundries[4] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[0].x,vBoundriesBox[0].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[4].y - vBoundriesBox[0].y)/2.0f), vBoundriesBox[0].z);
        newBoundries[5] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[0].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[1].x - vBoundriesBox[0].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[0].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[4].y - vBoundriesBox[0].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[0].z);
        newBoundries[6] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[0].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[1].x - vBoundriesBox[0].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[0].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[4].y - vBoundriesBox[0].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[0].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[3].z - vBoundriesBox[0].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[7] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[0].x,vBoundriesBox[0].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[4].y - vBoundriesBox[0].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[0].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[3].z - vBoundriesBox[0].z)/2.0f));

        trees[0][0][0] = new Quadtree(this, newBoundries, level+1);

        // 0,1,0
        newBoundries[0] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[1].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[1].x - vBoundriesBox[0].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[0].y,vBoundriesBox[1][2]);
        newBoundries[1] = vBoundriesBox[1];
        newBoundries[2] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[1].x,vBoundriesBox[1].y,vBoundriesBox[1].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2][2] - vBoundriesBox[1][2])/2.0f));
        newBoundries[3] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[1].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[1].x - vBoundriesBox[0].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[1][1],vBoundriesBox[1][2] - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].z - vBoundriesBox[1].z)/2.0f));

        newBoundries[4] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[1].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[1].x - vBoundriesBox[0].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[1].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].y - vBoundriesBox[1].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[1].z);
        newBoundries[5] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[1].x,vBoundriesBox[1].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].y - vBoundriesBox[1].y)/2.0f), vBoundriesBox[1].z);
        newBoundries[6] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[1].x,vBoundriesBox[1].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].y - vBoundriesBox[1].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[1].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].z - vBoundriesBox[1].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[7] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[1].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[1].x - vBoundriesBox[0].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[1].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].y - vBoundriesBox[1].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[1].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].z - vBoundriesBox[1].z)/2.0f));

        trees[0][1][0] = new Quadtree(this, newBoundries, level+1);

        // 0,0,1
        newBoundries[0] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[3].x,vBoundriesBox[3].y,vBoundriesBox[3].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[3].z - vBoundriesBox[0].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[1] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[3].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].x - vBoundriesBox[3].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[3].y,vBoundriesBox[3].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[3].z - vBoundriesBox[0].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[2] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[3].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].x - vBoundriesBox[3].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[3].y,vBoundriesBox[3].z );
        newBoundries[3] = vBoundriesBox[3];

        newBoundries[4] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[3].x,vBoundriesBox[3].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].y - vBoundriesBox[3].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[3].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[3].z - vBoundriesBox[0].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[5] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[3].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].x - vBoundriesBox[3].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[3].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].y - vBoundriesBox[3].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[3].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[3].z - vBoundriesBox[0].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[6] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[3].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].x - vBoundriesBox[3].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[3].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].y - vBoundriesBox[3].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[3].z );
        newBoundries[7] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[3].x,vBoundriesBox[3].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].y - vBoundriesBox[3].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[3].z);

        trees[0][0][1] = new Quadtree(this, newBoundries, level+1);

        // 0,1,1
        newBoundries[0] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[2].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].x - vBoundriesBox[3].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[2].y,vBoundriesBox[2].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2][2] - vBoundriesBox[1][2])/2.0f));
        newBoundries[1] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[2].x,vBoundriesBox[2].y,vBoundriesBox[2].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].z - vBoundriesBox[1].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[2] = vBoundriesBox[2];
        newBoundries[3] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[2].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].x - vBoundriesBox[3].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[2].y,vBoundriesBox[2].z );

        newBoundries[4] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[2].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].x - vBoundriesBox[3].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[2].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].y - vBoundriesBox[2].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[2].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].z - vBoundriesBox[1].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[5] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[2].x,vBoundriesBox[2].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].y - vBoundriesBox[2].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[2].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].z - vBoundriesBox[1].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[6] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[2].x,vBoundriesBox[2].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].y - vBoundriesBox[2].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[2].z);
        newBoundries[7] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[2].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[2].x - vBoundriesBox[3].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[2].y - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].y - vBoundriesBox[2].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[2].z);

        trees[0][1][1] = new Quadtree(this, newBoundries, level+1);

        // 1,0,0
        newBoundries[0] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[4].x,vBoundriesBox[4].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[4].y - vBoundriesBox[0].y)/2.0f), vBoundriesBox[4].z);
        newBoundries[1] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[4].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].x - vBoundriesBox[4].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[4].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[4].y - vBoundriesBox[0].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[4].z);
        newBoundries[2] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[4].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].x - vBoundriesBox[4].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[4].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[4].y - vBoundriesBox[0].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[4].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].z - vBoundriesBox[4].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[3] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[4].x,vBoundriesBox[4].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[4].y - vBoundriesBox[0].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[4].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].z - vBoundriesBox[4].z)/2.0f));

        newBoundries[4] = vBoundriesBox[4];
        newBoundries[5] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[4].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].x - vBoundriesBox[4].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[4].y,vBoundriesBox[4].z );
        newBoundries[6] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[4].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].x - vBoundriesBox[4].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[4].y,vBoundriesBox[4].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].z - vBoundriesBox[4].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[7] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[4].x,vBoundriesBox[4].y,vBoundriesBox[4].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].z - vBoundriesBox[4].z)/2.0f));

        trees[1][0][0] = new Quadtree(this, newBoundries, level+1);

        // 1,1,0
        newBoundries[0] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[5].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[4].x - vBoundriesBox[5].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[5].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].y - vBoundriesBox[1].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[5].z);
        newBoundries[1] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[5].x,vBoundriesBox[5].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].y - vBoundriesBox[1].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[5].z);
        newBoundries[2] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[5].x,vBoundriesBox[5].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].y - vBoundriesBox[1].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[5].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].z - vBoundriesBox[6].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[3] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[5].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[4].x - vBoundriesBox[5].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[5].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].y - vBoundriesBox[1].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[5].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].z - vBoundriesBox[6].z)/2.0f));

        newBoundries[4] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[5].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[4].x - vBoundriesBox[5].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[5].y,vBoundriesBox[5].z);
        newBoundries[5] = vBoundriesBox[5];
        newBoundries[6] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[5].x,vBoundriesBox[5].y,vBoundriesBox[5].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].z - vBoundriesBox[5].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[7] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[5].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[4].x - vBoundriesBox[5].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[5].y,vBoundriesBox[5].z - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[5].z - vBoundriesBox[6].z)/2.0f));

        trees[1][1][0] = new Quadtree(this, newBoundries, level+1);

        // 1,0,1
        newBoundries[0] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[7].x,vBoundriesBox[7].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].y - vBoundriesBox[3].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[7].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].z - vBoundriesBox[4].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[1] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[7].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].x - vBoundriesBox[6].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[7].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].y - vBoundriesBox[3].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[7].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[4].z - vBoundriesBox[7].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[2] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[7].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].x - vBoundriesBox[6].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[7].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].y - vBoundriesBox[3].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[7].z );
        newBoundries[3] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[7].x,vBoundriesBox[7].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].y - vBoundriesBox[3].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[7].z );

        newBoundries[4] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[7].x,vBoundriesBox[7].y,vBoundriesBox[7][2] + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].z - vBoundriesBox[4].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[5] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[7].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].x - vBoundriesBox[6].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[7].y,vBoundriesBox[7].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].z - vBoundriesBox[4].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[6] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[7].x + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[7].x - vBoundriesBox[6].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[7].y,vBoundriesBox[7].z );
        newBoundries[7] = vBoundriesBox[7];

        trees[1][0][1] = new Quadtree(this, newBoundries, level+1);

        // 1,1,1
        newBoundries[0] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[6].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].x - vBoundriesBox[7].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[6].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].y - vBoundriesBox[2].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[6].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].z - vBoundriesBox[5].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[1] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[6].x,vBoundriesBox[6].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].y - vBoundriesBox[2].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[6].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].z - vBoundriesBox[5].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[2] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[6].x,vBoundriesBox[6].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].y - vBoundriesBox[2].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[6].z);
        newBoundries[3] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[6].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].x - vBoundriesBox[7].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[6].y + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].y - vBoundriesBox[2].y)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[6].z);

        newBoundries[4] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[6].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].x - vBoundriesBox[7].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[6].y,vBoundriesBox[6].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].z - vBoundriesBox[5].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[5] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[6].x,vBoundriesBox[6].y,vBoundriesBox[6].z + (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].z - vBoundriesBox[5].z)/2.0f));
        newBoundries[6] = vBoundriesBox[6];
        newBoundries[7] = glm::vec3(vBoundriesBox[6].x - (std::abs(vBoundriesBox[6].x - vBoundriesBox[7].x)/2.0f),vBoundriesBox[6].y,vBoundriesBox[6].z );

        trees[1][1][1] = new Quadtree(this, newBoundries, level+1);
        leaf = false;
    }

    while (!this->objects.empty())
    {
        Element* obj = this->objects.back();
        this->objects.pop_back();
        if(contains(trees[0][0][0],obj))
        {
            trees[0][0][0]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[0][0][0]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[0][0][1],obj))
        {
            trees[0][0][1]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[0][0][1]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[0][1][0],obj))
        {
            trees[0][1][0]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[0][1][0]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[0][1][1],obj))
        {
            trees[0][1][1]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[0][1][1]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[1][0][0],obj))
        {
            trees[1][0][0]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[1][0][0]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[1][0][1],obj))
        {
            trees[1][0][1]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[1][0][1]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[1][1][0],obj))
        {
            trees[1][1][0]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[1][1][0]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[1][1][1],obj))
        {
            trees[1][1][1]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[1][1][1]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
            {
                trees[i][j][k]->Update();
            }
        }
    }
}

bool Quadtree::contains(Quadtree* child, Element* object)
{
    if(object->pos[0] >= child->vBoundriesBox[0][0] && object->pos[0] <= child->vBoundriesBox[1][0] &&
       object->pos[1] >= child->vBoundriesBox[4][1] && object->pos[1] <= child->vBoundriesBox[0][1] &&
       object->pos[2] >= child->vBoundriesBox[3][2] && object->pos[2] <= child->vBoundriesBox[0][2])
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

and in my main file I am adding elements into tree like this:

```
void AddTreeElements(Quadtree* tree, glm::vec3* boundries, Graph& graph)
{
    for(auto& node:graph.NodeVector())
    {
        node.parent_group = nullptr;
        if(node.pos[0] < boundries[1][0] && node.pos[0] > boundries[0][0] &&
                node.pos[1] > boundries[4][1] && node.pos[1] < boundries[1][1] &&
                node.pos[2] < boundries[0][2] && node.pos[2] > boundries[3][2])
        {
            tree->AddObject(&node.second);
            continue;
        }

        if(node.pos[0] < boundries[0][0])
        {
            boundries[0][0] = node.pos[0]-1.0f;
            boundries[3][0] = node.pos[0]-1.0f;
            boundries[4][0] = node.pos[0]-1.0f;
            boundries[7][0] = node.pos[0]-1.0f;
        }
        else if(node.pos[0] > boundries[1][0])
        {
            boundries[1][0] = node.pos[0]+1.0f;
            boundries[2][0] = node.pos[0]+1.0f;
            boundries[5][0] = node.pos[0]+1.0f;
            boundries[6][0] = node.pos[0]+1.0f;
        }

        if(node.pos[1] < boundries[4][1])
        {
            boundries[4][1] = node.pos[1]-1.0f;
            boundries[5][1] = node.pos[1]-1.0f;
            boundries[6][1] = node.pos[1]-1.0f;
            boundries[7][1] = node.pos[1]-1.0f;
        }
        else if(node.pos[1] > boundries[0][1])
        {
            boundries[0][1] = node.pos[1]+1.0f;
            boundries[1][1] = node.pos[1]+1.0f;
            boundries[2][1] = node.pos[1]+1.0f;
            boundries[3][1] = node.pos[1]+1.0f;
        }

        if(node.pos[2] < boundries[3][2])
        {
            boundries[2][2] = node.pos[2]-1.0f;
            boundries[3][2] = node.pos[2]-1.0f;
            boundries[6][2] = node.pos[2]-1.0f;
            boundries[7][2] = node.pos[2]-1.0f;
        }
        else if(node.pos[2] > boundries[0][2])
        {
            boundries[0][2] = node.pos[2]+1.0f;
            boundries[1][2] = node.pos[2]+1.0f;
            boundries[4][2] = node.pos[2]+1.0f;
            boundries[5][2] = node.pos[2]+1.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Because it is octree I am using box to visualize it and test if it's working correctly. Also, `boundries` array represents this box and this is how I am numbering corners:

[image: Box description]

As for the speed I've run sample test by randomly placing new nodes and this is how time/elements plot looks like:

[image: Speed plots]

Is it correct behavior when I am changing `MAX_LEVELS` value?